# ExtJS 3.3 Format.Util.Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer returning NaN

Tags: javascript, extjs

The Store

```
var timesheet = new Ext.data.JsonStore(
    {
        root: 'timesheetEntries',
        url: 'php/scripts/timecardEntry.script.php',
        storeId: 'timesheet',
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'user_id', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'ticket_number', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'start_time', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'stop_time', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'client_id', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'is_billable', type: 'integer' }
        ]
    }
);
```

A section of my GridPanel code:

```
columns: [
    {
        id: 'ticket_number',
        header: 'Ticket #',
        dataIndex: 'ticket_number'
    },
    {
        id: 'description',
        header: 'Description',
        dataIndex: 'description'
    },
    {
        id: 'start_time',
        header: 'Start',
        dataIndex: 'start_time',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y H:i:s')
    }
...
```

From the server, I receive this JSON string:

```
{
   timesheetEntries:[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "user_id":"1",
         "description":null,
         "start_time":"2010-11-13 11:30:00",
         "stop_time":"2010-11-13 15:50:10",
         "client_id":null,
         "is_billable":"0"
      }
```

My grid panel renders fine. However, my start and stop time columns read 'NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN:NaN' and I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data has `"2010-11-13 11:30:00"` shouldn't your format be `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`?

**EDIT:** Sorry, the grid config should be OK -- I was referring to the `dateFormat` value in your store's field definition, which should be `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` so that your incoming data can be properly mapped to your column model.  You should also include `type: 'date'`.  You're not showing your store config, but the problem is likely one of those things being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

function renderDate(v,params,record)
{
    var dt = new Date(v);
    if (!isNaN(dt.getDay())) {
       return dt.format('d/m/Y');
    }
    return '-';
}

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way to do it:

```
return Ext.util.Format.date(val,'m/d/Y');
```

Comment: if in case of value is `undefined` or `null` then it will also return `NaN`

Comment: @N.Jadhav i hv already tested this case, it will always return blank either `undefined` or `null` .. not `NaN` ;)