# ExtJS Version 5.0 : How to parse a date UTC?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, extjs

I have following 2 dates ->

```
Ext.util.Format.date('2016-03-16T17:49:53Z', 'm/d/y')
```

produces 03/16/16
But

```
 Ext.util.Format.date('2016-03-16 19:25:59 UTC', 'm/d/y')
```

produces Nan/Nan/Nan

How can I parse this date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExtJS 3.3 Format.Util.Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer returning NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176039/extjs-3-3-format-util-ext-util-format-daterenderer-returning-nan)

Comment: The method expects a date object, otherwise it uses the native `Date.parse` with the passed value.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli How do I know the type of the Object? I am using something like this in my code instead of the date directly --> Ext.util.Format.date(record.get('creation_date'), 'm/d/y');

Comment: Well, I assume `creation_date` is coming from a server which should always send the same type, right?

Comment: I checked the date type and it is fine. The format is a problem

Comment: Which Version of ExtJS are you using ?